# Char* data changes when accessed

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

I am working on a c++ application that has a function

```
//ControllerCore.cpp
Report ControllerCore::GetReport() {
unsigned char buf[256];
int res = 0;
while (res == 0) {
    res = get_unsigned_char*(buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (res < 0)
        printf("Unable to read()\n");
#ifdef WIN32
    Sleep(50);
#else
    usleep(50 * 1000);
#endif

}

Report report = Report();
report.data = buf;
report.dataLength = res;
return report;
}
```

Report is defined as

```
//Report.h
struct Report
{
    public:
        unsigned char* data;
        int dataLength;
};
```

When ContollerCore::GetReport() returns it assigns report.data to the pointer to an array of unsigned characters that I can work with fine. But when the caller tries to print report.data the values of the array change.

```
//Main.cpp
int RequestReport() {

    Report report = core.GetReport();
    for (int i = 0; i < report.dataLength; i++) {
        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (int)report.data[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `report.data = buf;` turns `data` into a dangling pointer (`buf` is destroyed when the function returns)

Comment: Does `get_unsigned_char*(buf, sizeof(buf));`compile? Should it be: `*get_unsigned_char(buf, sizeof(buf));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local array.  As soon as `ControlerCore::GetReport` returns, `buf` goes out of scope and is destroyed.  Any attempt to access it after that leads to undefined behavior.

You need make `Report` actually hold the data directly.  The easiest way would be to use a `std::vector`:

```
struct Report
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;
    // don't need dataLength anymore since std::vector knows its size
};

Report ControllerCore::GetReport() {
    Report report;
    report.data.resize(256);
    int res = 0;
    while (res == 0) {
        res = get_data(report.data.data(), report.data.size());
    }
    report.data.resize(res);
    return report;
}
```

Now that `Report` has only one member it probably isn't needed anymore, and you could just return `std::vector<unsigned char>` directly instead.

If you want to avoid the dynamic allocation used by `std::vector`, you could use `std::array` (or a raw array) instead:

```
struct Report
{
    std::array<unsigned char, 256> data;
    size_t dataLength; // back now, since the length of the data won't match the size of the contianer
};

Report ControllerCore::GetReport() {
    Report report;
    int res = 0;
    while (res == 0) {
        res = get_data(report.data.data(), report.data.size());
    }
    report.dataLength = res;
    return report;
}
```

This avoids the dynamic allocation, but does incur an extra copy of the data since `std::array` can't be efficiently moved like `std::vector` can.  That means that unless dynamic allocation is especially slow on your platform, the `std::vector` version is probably going to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using report.data itself instead of buf.

```
Report ControllerCore::GetReport() {
Report report;
report.data=new char[256];
int res = 0;
while (res == 0) {
    res = get_unsigned_char*(report.data, sizeof(char)*256);
    if (res < 0)
        printf("Unable to read()\n");
#ifdef WIN32
    Sleep(50);
#else
    usleep(50 * 1000);
#endif

}

report.dataLength = res;
return report;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)*256` seeing as `buf` was max 256 length?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, so it's not really needed.